# Exit process created with CreateProcessWithLogonW on logout

Tags: c#, logout

On logon of a user i am starting a process as Administrator using CreateProcessWithLogonW in C#.

When the user now logs off, the program is not getting closed.

I want it to get closed when the user which started it using CreateProcessWithLogonW logs out. How do i do that?

There is no way i can keep the process executing CreateProcessWithLogonW running, so the program started as administrator has to kill itself.

Comment: Is it a Windows Service?

Comment: No, it isn't a windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a HiddenForm described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx Example 2. 
This was initially for Windows Services but also works with a Windows-Forms Application without a GUI. The reason why you don't get SessionEnding events in a Application without a GUI (also Console-Applications, Windows Services) is that it is send trough a Windows Message Pump which is only assigned to each open windows (basically).

For more information on Windows-Messages read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To get this Example really invisible (in xp) you also need

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.Visible = false;
```

in HiddenForm.InitializeComponent().

Answer (score 0):

If an application that issued CreateProcessWithLogonW is still running you can detect when Windows start to log out and close child application as well.
E.g using [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx)

Comment: No it's not running anymore after starting the program as Administrator. When using SystemEvents.SessionEnding in it i do not get any Events.

Comment: How do you start your C# application on logon? Is it possible to keep it running so it will get SessionEnding event and send some signal to the child application

Comment: Nope, there is no way i can be sure that it keeps running. Also, killing the application from the starter-program would not work because it is running with higher permissions. It needs to be killed from itself.